# PyOpenCL vs Clyther vs pure OpenCL and C99: what's the best for novice?

Tags: python, performance, opencl, pyopencl

I have a problem: fast linear systems solving (I have a lot of such systems). I'm going to solve it using GPU and OpenCL.

I love dynamic languages such as Ruby or Python and I got out of a habit of using low level languages like C.

So I have two simultaneous aims:

1. Develop such OpenCL solution for solving linear systems as fast as I
   can with as less efforts as possible.
2. Don't loose a lot in performance. I don't want to pay 2-10x deceleration for convenience, but I'm ready to pay 30-50% for work with high level language.

The best case for me is: almost python code compile in OpenCL C almost without waste.

I found such solutions: pure [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) C, [PyOpenCL](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl), [Clyther](http://clyther.sourceforge.net/).

With what should I start?

Comment: Do as much in C as you're comfortable with to do the calculation, use something like Cython to make a binding to your custom C library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is that trying to shoehorn a dynamic language into OpenCL is not worth the effort. You will lose most of what you like about Python, and probably not save much time for your effort in the end.

But I am speaking only of writing OpenCL kernels in Python. There is also the host application, which prepares and submits the kernels. If you like Python, I suggest writing the host app in pure Python with a wrapper like PyOpenCL to access the OpenCL API. Then, write your kernels in pure OpenCL and have your Python app submit them as-is. I believe this will get most of what you want from Python while costing almost nothing in performance.

Comment: PyOpenCL is very well written.  It saved me a lot of time.  I was able to modify my pure Python/Numpy Mandelbrot calculation to be over 250x faster.  The Numpy was not slow either!  It leveraged it C compile code a lot, but the PyOpenCL version made it look like a slug.  To top it off I am feeding both versions of the algorithm Numpy arrays as PyOpenCL has support for them.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part of programming with OpenCL is parallelizing your algorithm -- and that means writing your kernels.  Chances are, you will be spending the majority of your time tweaking and understanding your OpenCL C code, which AFAIK is your only choice for writing kernels.

That being the case, I say go for a pure C / OpenCL implementation.  Once you have the "boilerplate" OpenCL API portion up and running, you are not likely to have to change much of it.  If anything, you will be playing with things like the workgroup size you pass to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.

If you're a novice with CL, I say keep it simple.  Adding another software layer to the problem -- especially a problem as well defined as a linear solver -- only complicates your efforts.

EDIT:

I should add that you broaden your potential for online help / support when you use the standard OpenCL API.  If you choose to go with one of the python bindings, you might limit your potential support to the folks from those communities.